Involution on polynomial rings
A map $\ast$ on a ring $R$ is said to be involution if the following properties holds for each element of $a,b\in R$:

$(a+b)^\ast=a^\ast + b^\ast$
$(ab)^\ast=b^\ast a^\ast$
$(a^\ast)^\ast=a$.

I want to know that if $f(x)=a_0^\ast+a_1^\ast x+\cdot \cdot \cdot+a_n^\ast x^n$ is a polynomial in $R[x]$. Can I use the property of $\ast$ to write $f(x)=(a_0+a_1x+\cdot \cdot \cdot+a_n x^n)^\ast$, I mean how to use the $\ast$ on the indeterminate $x$.

$\ast$ operate on the elements of the ring, how can it operate on the elements of the polynomial rings.

Yes that's what I want to know how to operate it on polynomial rings

Without a definition, you can't just use it this way, but you are unlikely to confuse people if you use it this way. The problem is with polynomial evaluation. A key hint in the incompatibility is that the definition of involution is that it is about general nings, not just commutative rings, and  polynomial rings get trickier with non-commutative rings - in particular, polynomial evaluation is not a ring homomorphism for non-commutative rings.

But if you define it this way, it is an involution on $R[x].$

Only one person downvoted. We can't speak for whoever that is, but one is not "people."

Thanks @ThomasAndrews, it makes sense. I should define the involution on $R[x]$

Any involution $^{\ast}$ on $R$ naturally extends to an involution on $R[x]$ in the obvious way; we simply define
$$\left( f_0 + f_1 x + \dots + f_n x^n \right)^{\ast} = f_0^{\ast} + f_1^{\ast} x + \dots + f_n^{\ast} x^n$$
which is to say we apply the involution coefficient-by-coefficient. You need to check that the axioms still apply but this is not hard. This is a choice we make, and is a standard convention, but other choices are possible. For example we could send $x^k$ to $(-1)^k x^k$.
A disclaimer is necessary here about polynomial evaluation, for two distinct reasons. First is the noncommutativity issue raised by Thomas Andrews in the comments: if $R$ is noncommutative then the notation $R[x]$ is ambiguous and there are two possible constructions depending on whether you require $x$ to commute with every element of $R$ or not. If you do then the evaluation homomorphism $f(x) \mapsto f(a)$ doesn't exist unless $a$ is central, and if you don't then polynomials are not sums of monomials of the form $f_i x^i$ but are more complicated since you need to consider expressions like $fx^2 g x^3 h \dots $.
Second, even ignoring noncommutativity, there is still a slightly tricky thing to be careful of, which is that even in the commutative case we have $f(a)^{\ast} = f^{\ast}(a^{\ast})$ (rather than $f(a)^{\ast} = f^{\ast}(a)$).

Any basic paper or book you know who discussed these type of involutions
